# WPF Template Form

Tags: c#, c++, .net, wpf, flowdocument

I want to create a recipe application.  I would like the input to look and feel like you are editing a document.  If I were doing this in word, I'd create a template form for the user to use for the imput.

The form will look something like:

---

```
{Categoty} {Title}
{Image} {yield / nutrition info}

Ingredients
{bulleted list goes here}

Directions
{Numbered list goes here}

Notes / Comments
{Free form text goes here}
```

---

I tried doing this with a FlowDocument embedded im a RichTextBox, but could not figure it out.  I can store the info and populate the FlowDocument parts easy enough, but I could not figure out how to control editing to force bullets or numbering at certain places / keeping the user from changing the format, etc.

Can this be done in a FlowDocument?  If not, how can I create the bulleted / numbered list areas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating custom controls for the lists (custom grid supporting bulleted or numbered editable lists and using other controls for the various document parts to give me the control I want - I use an XML file for storing the pieces of the document and how to generate the FlowDocument (I hope this gives me the ease of updating the templates when I am asked to add something new)...  I only generate a FlowDocument for printing purposes.

I did not get all the functionality I wanted, but I made it work.  Now for my next project..

Answer (score 1):

Flow Documents are editable as long as you use RichTextBox as opposed to Page.

you might want to take a look at [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37368/WPF-Flow-Document-For-Beginners) or [this](http://michaelsync.net/2009/06/09/bindable-wpf-richtext-editor-with-xamlhtml-convertor) or even [this](http://www.drdobbs.com/windows/embed-custom-guis-in-wpf/209800469)

Comment: I guess you missed the part where I said I tried using the RichTextBox...  As long as I don't care about formatting and allow the user to change any text...  The thing is, I do care and have not been able to figure out how to do it that way.

Comment: sorry i did miss that, apologies